# Math for game theory

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I have read a bunch of book on Game Theory, and I find that one of the best is the the book of Osborne and Rubinstein. Nevertheless, *all* books which I found are not made for mathematician, meaning that they do not assume prior knowledge, in particular they do not assume measure theory, functional/complex analysis etc.

Is there any really formal and well-written book about game theory made for mathematician? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try Fudenberg and Tirole.

Comment: If you mean the one linked below, it is a rather standard textbook :/  http://read.pudn.com/downloads146/ebook/635671/MIT%20Press%20-%20Game%20Theory--Fudenberg%20&%20Tirole--579p.pdf

Comment: This is hot these days, and presume a fair amount of knowledge: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461485070

Comment: Try Gintis, Game Theory Evolving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by prior knowledge, but I would give a couple of books which requires more mathematical sophistication than Osborne and Rubinstein. If you are looking for a specific area in game theory then this list may not be useful for you.

1. Game Theory by Maschler, Solan and Zamir: This book is relatively new and it includes almost everything one needs to know about game theory (both cooperative and non-cooperative). In the mathematical appendix it covers necessary background for existence theorem.
2. Game Theory for Economic Analysis by Ichiishi: This is a pretty old book, but it is very well written and it assumes a great deal of mathematical knowledge. Yet, the initial chapters discuss continuity notions for set valued maps(uhc-lhc), properties of convex sets and fixed points.
3. Game Theory by Owen: This is also another old book, but  it is still used in various courses in different places. It has traditional definition-theorem-proof structure.